# Elasticsearch uri sort by fieldname

Tags: sorting, hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

How to order particular field in ES 5.4 version through query url

```
http://localhost:9200/companies/emp/_search?q=*&sort=name:desc
```

here i am searching emp and displaying emp name in descending order. 
I am getting thi exception

```
Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://localhost:9200/companies/emp/_search?q=*&sort=name.keyword:desc

You need to put keyword after name

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are trying to sort your data using a field with type "text". As the error says, you should change the type from "text" to "keyword" or enabling fielddata, but I would recommend you to read this infohttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html before enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good explanation of fielddata, and why sorting on a text field doesn't just work out of the box: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

In short, text fields are run through analyzers which allow you to get hits on searches where you're close, but not quite an exact match. For instance, from the link posted above, you can search for "new" or "york" and find a value of "New York" because it's been run through an analyzer.

If your field was a keyword though, you'd have to search on the *exact* value to find it.

Now, how that relates to sorting: Operations like sorting and aggregations need to know the *exact* value of the field to be able to perform operations like that on them. When run through analyzers, the analyzed value is stored, not the exact value.

I'd recommend slightly changing your mapping to include both types with something like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "emp": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks wholevinski.. used above one for query url.. thanks for valuable suggestion